# Why do people classify Microsoft Azure as Platform-as-a-Service?

Tags: azure, cloud, saas, paas, iaas

I had a lecture in college which shortly focused on cloud computing. 
When seeing through the material, I found the professor categorized Microsoft Azure as Platform-as-a-Service.

In Addition to that, I recently gave a presentation which also partly focused on Azure, and afterwards was asked which of the three models (IaaS, SaaS or PaaS) Azure would belong to.

I replied that it offers solutions for all three models and therefore, a categorization cannot be limited to just one of the models. My professor (a different one than before) said I was partly wrong, classifying it as PaaS with additional possibilities for IaaS and SaaS.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Platform_as_a_service_(PaaS)) also lists Microsoft Azure as an example for PaaS.

Question: Can anyone tell me why Azure is just sort of "labeled" as PaaS?

Just to clarify: The presentation I gave was some sort of oral exam with viewers, I did not have the guts to start a discussion with the prof evaluating me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor was right, especially with the statement "classifying it as PaaS with additional possibilities for IaaS and SaaS."  As you said yourself, Wikipedia also lists Microsoft Azure as an example for PaaS.  It comes down to this. SaaS exists on top of an underlying PaaS.  What makes Azure a PaaS is their data centers allowing you access into it plus Azure Active Directory authenticating and authorizing into it on top of it.  Without these you could not deliver the SaaS model such as Office 365 which sits on top of it.  Microsoft Office 365 is a SaaS offering, built on top of Azure.  When I interviewed for a Microsoft position a few years ago, I was asked what was "Azure"?  I actually missed this question, because I wasn’t up on Azure at the time.  The correct answer told to me then was "cloud platform".  So there you have it.

Comment: `What makes Azure a PaaS is their data centers allowing you access into it plus Azure Active Directory authenticating and authorizing into it on top of it` - IMHO, this is not the right reason for classifying Azure as PaaS.

Comment: azure is not paas. azure is azure. another cloud provider. all of them (virtually) are saas-paas-iaas

Comment: I actually agree with t-heron here.  The "platform" is the equipment and operating systems the SaaS sits on top.  Azure AD powers the authentication/authorization processes.

Comment: @JohnRSmith With that logic Amazon AWS should also be classified as PaaS as it also allows you to access into their data centers. But we all know that AWS is primarily considered as an IaaS provider. In any case, I think this question is not suitable for this forum as it is primarily opinion based (which is what we're doing...giving our opinions :)).

Comment: @GauravMantri - Easy logic.  Azure is PaaS first, then SaaS and IaaS on top of that.  You can't have SaaS and IaaS without PaaS underneath.  Don;t understand what you're not getting here.

Comment: so whats wrong with Azure being IaaS? do you have any numbers? i suspect that couple of years ago IaaS made much more than PaaS on Azure in terms of revenue. (and maybe still is)

Comment: @JohnRSmith...Respectfully I disagree. You can't build PaaS and SaaS without IaaS. So IaaS is must. A good example is Heroku which is a PaaS built on top of AWS IaaS. Whether a provider choose to expose underlying infrastructure as a service is a different matter all together. And this is what initially Microsoft did with Azure. Only after 2012, they formally got into IaaS.

Comment: IaaS and SaaS are the revenue drivers.  But Microsoft themselves refers to Azure as their cloud platform.  Heard it from more than one person.  That's PaaS.  We're quiblling with nuance here.

Comment: Cloud platform != paas. jesus.

Comment: @4c74356b41 There's absolutely nothing wrong with it. We all know Azure is all of them. I think its a perception that people have about Azure that it is primarily PaaS (which is where Azure started back in 2008 with their Cloud Services).

Comment: I'm just agreeing with Wikipedia, the Professor, and T-Heron on the assertion that PaaS is the base of Azure.  Of course it's also IaaS and SaaS as well.  In the words of one immortal, can't we all just get along?  :-)  Good day everyone.

Comment: This is why people are voting to close this as opinion-based ;)